# Aggregate Function (count, max) and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am using the [Chinook database](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation) to practice some SQL, and am attempting to find the most popular album purchased by each country (where country is determined by BillingCountry in the Invoice table). My solution (in MySQL) is as follows:

```
SELECT TitleCount, Title, BillingCountry
    FROM (SELECT max(TitleCount) AS TitleCount, BillingCountry
            FROM (SELECT count(Title) AS TitleCount, BillingCountry
                    FROM Invoice NATURAL JOIN InvoiceLine
                         NATURAL JOIN Track NATURAL JOIN Album
                    GROUP BY Title, BillingCountry) AS counts
            GROUP BY BillingCountry) AS maxCounts NATURAL JOIN
         (SELECT count(Title) AS TitleCount, Title, BillingCountry
            FROM Invoice NATURAL JOIN InvoiceLine
                 NATURAL JOIN Track NATURAL JOIN Album
            GROUP BY Title, BillingCountry) AS counts;
```

The aliased subquery maxCounts finds, for each country, the most number of purchases made, and counts finds, for each country, how many times each Album was purchased. The outer query then combines the two with a natural join to effectively say, for each country, display the most purchased Album.

A brief overview of what the tables (only relevant attributes shown) look like below for Invoice and Album, which are the two most pertinent for this question. Invoice:

```
InvoiceId(PK) | BillingCountry
--------------+---------------
1             | USA
2             | Norway
3             | USA
4             | France
5             | USA
6             | France
```

Album:

```
AlbumId(PK) | Title
------------+------
1           | Facelift
2           | Big Ones
3           | Out of Exile
```

There are a number of tables between Invoice and Album that relate them. I would like to be able to list for each country which album was the most purchased. So, if the following was how many times each album was purchased by a country (essentially, the `counts` subquery from above):

```
count(Title) | Title        | Country
-------------+--------------+--------
3            | Facelift     | USA
1            | Out of Exile | USA
2            | Big Ones     | France
1            | Out of Exile | France
1            | Out of Exile | Norway
```

What I would want to see in my result is only the most popular Album (represented by `Title`) for each country:

```
max(Title) | Title        | Country
-----------+--------------+--------
3          | Facelift     | USA
2          | Big Ones     | France
1          | Out of Exile | Norway
```

Is there a more concise way to write this? My first inclination was to use `count` and `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` to find songs with the max count, something like the following:

```
SELECT count(Title) AS TitleCount, Title, BillingCountry
  FROM Invoice NATURAL JOIN InvoiceLine NATURAL JOIN Track NATURAL JOIN Album
  GROUP BY Title, BillingCountry
  HAVING count(Title) = <finds max count>
```

But it seems like the `HAVING` subquery must know what the current country is in order to find the max for that country.

Comment: Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`!  It is a bug waiting to happen.  Be explicit about the columns used for joining.  `NATURAL JOIN` doesn't even use properly declared foreign key relationships.

Comment: Your current query is in a mess.  Can you show us sample input data, along with the output you expect?